# How to handle different date formats in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to handle different date format in a Spring MVC controller?

I know that setting something like this

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}
```

I can handle `dd/MM/yyyy` format, but what if i want to parse also dates in `yyyyMMddhhmmss` format? Should I add multiple `CustomDateEditor`s in my controller?

Comment: enforce only one date format on the client side too, jquery ui datepicker etc make it easy

Comment: This is rather strange - I understand that you can *parse* the dates in different formats with a custom editor or even better a type converter - but how are you going to *display* them? It think that you should implement your own type for dates that will encapsulate information about its representation which seems a little odd thing to do anyway

Comment: I think it should be represented in the same format it gonna be read, else you gonna have issues. Here you have only one formatter, and only one format, in cases when you have multiples formats, it should take the first valid one,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at a time you receive only one format of date, then you could simply create one instance of `DateFormat` based on format

**for example**

Decide the format based on the input

```
DateFormat df = null;
if(recievedDate.indexOf("//")!=-1){
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
}else{
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Skipy

```
public class LenientDateParser extends PropertyEditorSupport {

private static final List<String> formats = new ArrayList<String>();

private String outputFormat;

static{
    formats.add("dd-MM-yyyy HH:ss");
    formats.add("dd/MM/yyyy HH:ss");
    formats.add("dd-MM-yyyy");
    formats.add("dd/MM/yyyy");
    formats.add("dd MMM yyyy");
    formats.add("MMM-yyyy HH:ss");
    formats.add("MMM-yyyy");
    formats.add("MMM yyyy");
}

public LenientDateParser(String outputFormat){
    this.outputFormat = outputFormat;
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(text))
        return;
    DateTime dt = null;
    for(String format : formats){

        try{

            dt = DateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format));

            break;

        }catch(Exception e){
            if(log.isDebugEnabled())
                log.debug(e,e);
        }
    }
    if(dt != null)
        setValue(dt.toDate());
}

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    Date date = (Date) getValue();

    if(date == null)
        return "";

    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(outputFormat);

    return f.print(date.getTime());

}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need it only at puntual cases, you can register the custom editor attached to a field in the form:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", this.getLocale(context));
DateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss SSS", this.getLocale(context));
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateTimeFormat, true));
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "name.of.input", new CustomDateEditor(dateTimeFormat, true));
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this. the above can go out of whack pretty soon.

```
       public class MostLenientDateParser {
           private final List<String> supportedFormats;

           public MostLenientDateParser(List<String> supportedFormats) {
               this.supportedFormats = supportedFormats;
           }

           public Date parse(String dateValue) {
               for(String candidateFormat: supportedFormats) {
                   Date date = lenientParse(dateValue, candidateFormat);
                   if (date != null) {
                       return date;
                   }
               }
               throw new RuntimeException("tried so many formats, non matched");
           }

           private Date lenientParse(String dateCandidate, String dateFormat) {
               try {
                   return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(dateCandidate);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   return null;
               }
           }
       }
```

This could also be referenced through Spring Converters via a CustomDateEditor implementation for form-data binding.

Answer (score 3):

For others having the same question, if you are using spring 3 You can use the awesome @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy") in the field of your model.

Just make sure to register a conversionService with your org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter

You can have as much as you want of @DateTimeFormat in the same bean.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great idea to have lenient date formatters when dealing with multiple locales. A date like 10/11/2013 will get parsed correctly with both dd/MM/YYYY and MM/dd/YYYY

Comment: You just should not specify those ambiguous cases. This is not the case wanted.